# MySQL Select working in WorkBench, But not in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to get the following to work, i have read numerous online posts about this, but nothing seems to be working.

The Query String works when i run it in MySQLWorkbench.
I am using XPath to retrieve all ExternalId's and store them into a list.

```
        String getExternalIds = "/FundShareClass/Fund/PortfolioList/Portfolio/Holding/HoldingDetail/@_ExternalId";
        List<String> externalIdList = new ArrayList<String>();

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(getExternalIds).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
        {
            externalIdList.add(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() + '\n');
        }


        Connection conn = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TestDb";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "";

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        System.out.print("Connection Made to Mysql Database");

for(String externalId : externalIdList)
            {
                 try
                 {
                     String currentId = externalId;

                     String query = "SELECT * FROM StructuredMappings WHERE managerCode=?";
                     PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                     ps.setString(1, externalId);

                     ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();


                     Boolean response = rs.next();
                     System.out.println(response);

                     while(rs.next())
                     {
                         System.out.println("MAPPING CODE FOUND");

                         String ISIN = rs.getString("ISIN");
                         String idType = rs.getString("type");

                         System.out.println(ISIN +" , " +idType);
                     }
```

The Boolean Response Prints out False for all valid id's..

Comment: have you done any debugging to see what `externalId` is for each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Yes, i have printed out all the externalId's inside the loop, and manually done a select in MySQL workbench. - Where they are all valid

Comment: Should `managerCode` be a `String` or a number?

Comment: managerCode is of type Varchar in MySQL Workbench

Comment: Count you paste the output so we can better analyze it ? Or a brief snippet if its too long

Comment: The provided code prints out the following.
false
230267

false
196393

false
SBS19

false
HILB04

Comment: Try removing the new instance of Java class loader
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: @santiago92,  Removed - Still the same

Comment: @Beanz can u paste the output error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you populate `externalIdList` you add a `'\n'` to every id.

I don't know about your ids but I guess that you should drop the linefeed.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++)
    externalIdList.add(nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
```